# Eigen Library : real time processing

Tags: matrix, real-time, eigen

I'm trying to use `Eigen` with no heap allocation for real time processing.

As far as I know:

```
Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic> allocates on the stack
Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic, AutoAlign, 1, 1> allocates on the heap
and Matrix<double, 1, 1> allocates on the stack;
```

One way to use `Eigen` in real time is to resize matrices *at startup*, with a big size, then using only a fraction of this size.

My question is : with functions like : `Rm.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(Rhs)`, how can I perform such computation with dynamic matrices?
The function will take the whole size of the matrix to do the operation which is not good as we want only a portion of this size to be treated.
Also we obviously can't `use .resize()`

So how to perform operations with real-time processing?

Answer (score 0):

Real-time processing usually involves the same work being done repeatedly, on a fixed schedule. One approach to dynamic memory allocation then is to have a contiguous chunk (a pool) of memory that you linearly allocate from. You then mark all of this memory as free at the end of the processing period. The allocation cost is O(1), the deallocation cost is O(1), and for a given amount of work you can easily guarantee that all memory allocations will be satisfied. So, one solution is to use a custom allocator.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [block() method](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html):

```
Rm.block<3, 3>(0,0).colPivHouseholderQr().solve(Rhs)
```